# Deleting Returned SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I delete the records returned by the following query?

```
Select HL.User from "Hobby List" HL 
INNER JOIN (Select SUBSTRING(Code,1,10) Code,Count(SUBSTRING(CODE,1,10))
AS Occurances from Patient where length(Patient.Code) > 10
Group By SUBSTRING(Code,1,10)
Having COUNT(SUBSTRING(Code,1,10)) > 1) P
on SUBSTRING(HL.User,1,10) = P.Code
Group By HL.User
```

I tried to delete the records by using a "delete if exists" approach which was either wrong or I didn't do it properly because it deleted all the records in the table instead of just the ones returned by my query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM 'Hobby List'
WHERE User  IN 
(

Select HL.User from "Hobby List" HL 
INNER JOIN (Select SUBSTRING(Code,1,10) Code,Count(SUBSTRING(CODE,1,10))
AS Occurances from Patient where length(Patient.Code) > 10
Group By SUBSTRING(Code,1,10)
Having COUNT(SUBSTRING(Code,1,10)) > 1) P
on SUBSTRING(HL.User,1,10) = P.Code
Group By HL.User

)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM "Hobby List" HL WHERE HL.User IN (your query here)
```

This should do it quite well, I've used this quite a few times in other scenarios.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Thanks that worked great.  I just didn't need to assign a name HL for hobby list in the delete from clause it was giving me an error because I was naming it in my query twice.  But was easy enough to sort out.